# Passing RegExp objects between content scripts and main add-on script

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am having an issue whereby I create a `RegExp` object in a content script and pass it as part of an object back to the main script using `self.port.emit()`.
Somewhere along the way it seems to lose its identity as a RegExp and also its toString abilities. The following returns false in the main script, but true in the content script:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(regexp) == '[object RegExp]';
regexp instanceof RegExp;
```

Interestingly for Arrays passed in the same way the following is true:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == '[object Array]';
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: At least in Chrome, trying to covert an expression to JSON results in an empty object: `{foo: /test/}` becomes `"{"foo":{}}"`. JSON does not know regex types. I assume the same is happening in your case.

Comment: Sounds plausible, is annoying though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Add-on SDK doesn't pass objects around when you send messages, only strings - it essentially calls [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on one side and then [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the other. The result is easy to predict:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(new RegExp()));
```

This gives you `"{}"`. In other words, `JSON.stringify()` treats "custom" objects as normal objects without any properties, object prototypes and such are ignored. What you get in your main code is a plain object, same as if you call `new Object()`.

If you need to pass a regular expression to your main code - send `regexp.source`, create an actual regular expression on the other side. Sending actual objects around isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks, are you sure about  "`JSON.stringify()` treats "custom" objects as normal objects without any properties" though? Any custom defined fields seem to be preserved.

Comment: @Arth: Well, custom properties are preserved - but regexp-specific ones (meaning: defined on the prototype) aren't.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you just sent the regex pattern instead of the whole rexexp object? e.g. `encodeURIComponent(regexp.source);`

Comment: I didn't want to target the regexp specifically because the JSON object gets recursively turned into a custom script at the other end and includes strings and Arrays. I think I prefer JSON.stringify() to URI encoding, but this is basically what I have done.